# Sample from repeated binomial distribtion

Tags: python, random

I have a repeated binomial test (p = probability of success, n = no of trials). I want to randomly generate the number of successes.

I could just generate n random numbers, but that is too inefficient. i.e. not like this:

```
def successes(p, n):
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        if random.random() < p:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I want this to be an exact sample (not a normal or other approximation) as this is going to be used repeatedly for highly skewed distributions.

I feel that this could be done using the density functions etc ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function ) but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: You say that it is too inefficient, but how do you know that it is inefficient?  Have you tested, or is this just a guess?

Comment: This is not a "repeated binomial distribution", it is just a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.random.binomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) does it.